# Can I set <xsl:output/> attributes conditionally in an XSLT stylesheet?

Tags: xslt, saxon, docbook

I'm trying to automate some xslt transformations, and I need a way to set xsl:output attributes based on the content in the XML files being transformed.

Specifically, I want to look into the XML files, grab the lang attribute from the root element, and set attributes based on the lang value.

I've tried the following:

```
<xsl:param name="language">
    <xsl:value-of select="//*/@lang"/>
</xsl:param>

<xsl:output method="xml" xmlns:saxon="http://icl.com/saxon" encoding="utf-8">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$language != 'ja'">
            <xsl:attribute name="saxon:character-representation"><xsl:value-of select="'native'"/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:attribute name="saxon:character-representation"><xsl:value-of select="'hex'"/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:output>
```

...but my parser informs me that the xsl:output element must be empty.

Is there a way to do something like this in the context of a style sheet, or am I going to have to manipulate these attributes at a higher level?

Comment: Do note that underline problem (control how non-ASCII characters will be represented on output) is better addressed ussing `encoding="us-ascii"`. [Saxon doc](https://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/extensions/output-extras/character-representation.html)

Comment: Is that Saxon 6 with XSLT 1 or Saxon 9 with XSLT 2 or 3?

Comment: Attributes of `xsl:output` instruction aren't [_"attribute value templates"_](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#value-templates). Thus, if your want to define those by some XML document content, you will need to perform a two step transformation: transform/create an stylesheet with the correct attribute, then do the proper transformation.

Comment: In XSLT 2/3 and with Saxon 9 PE or EE, with `xsl:result-document`, you can use attribute value templates, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#creating-result-trees, I haven't checked whether that holds for that particular Saxon specific extension attribute as well.

Comment: @MartinHonnin - Saxon 6 with XSLT 1

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged this `docbook`, which I suspect is why you're still using the ancient Saxon 6.5.5 processor and its `http://icl.com/saxon` namespace. However, the docbook stylesheets can be made to work with a modern version of Saxon, which allows you to choose serialization attributes dynamically in an `xsl:result-document` instruction.

An alternative is to override the `xsl:output` properties from the Java API or command line. However, that's awkward in your case where you want to make the properties dependent on something in the source document.